# Add unit/integration tests to NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, testing, pipeline

I have this piece of NodeJS code which connects to a MySQL database.  How can add unit/integration tests to this piece of code before the build stage in the Jenkins Pipeline(only if the tests pass, then the build will start)?

In this case, the tests should check that

1. Connectivity to the database is working
2. The correct text is returned from the SQL query.

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express();
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    
    require('dotenv').config({ debug: true })
    console.log(process.env) // remove this after you've confirmed it working
    
    // parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    //create database connection
    const conn = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'dev-mysqldb',
      user: 'mysqluser',
      password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      database: 'hello_world'
    });
    
    //connect to database
    conn.connect((err) =>{
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log('Mysql Connected...');
    });
    
    //show all products
    app.get('/',(req, res) => {
      let sql = "SELECT * FROM messages";
      let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    //    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
        res.send(results);
      });
    });
    
    //Server listening
    app.listen(80,() =>{
      console.log('Server started on port 80...');
    });
```

Comment: The problem is, your code is not testable, because you dont export anything. Split your code into smaler chunks (e.g connect to db, handle http query, etc) and test each chunk. In your "app" you just connect then the chunks. As it is, you cant write a test suite.

Comment: Hi Marc,  could you show an example of how this can be done?  Thanks.